# How to specify that an abstract method's return type is the subclass's type

Tags: scala

How, in an abstract class, can I specify that a method's return value has the same type as the concrete class that it's a member of?

For example:

```
abstract class Genotype {
  def makeRandom(): Genotype  // must return subclass type
  def mutate(): Genotype      // must return subclass type
}
```

I'd like to say that whenever you call `mutate()` on a concrete Genotype class, you're sure to get back another instance of the same Genotype class.

I'd prefer not to use a type parameter in the manner of `Genotype[SpecificGenotype259]`, since that type parameter is likely to proliferate all over the code (also, it's redundant and confusing). I'd prefer to define concrete Genotype classes by extending from various traits.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and cannot test: have you tried self.type as return type?!

Comment: With `self =>` and `def mutate(): self.type` in the abstract class, I'm getting `found: this.Genotype \\ required: Genotype.this.type` in the concrete class. Doesn't `self.type` define a class that is limited to the specific object rather than the object's lowest class?

Comment: strange; I've tried `def mutate(): this.type` and it works. Edit the post with what you try and what you get

Comment: Yes, `self.type` or `this.type` is limited to the specific object `this`. It works for @maks because @maks didn't write a concrete class that returned a value other than `this`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner you're right, I've created subclass with no parameters and returned `new Subclass` from `def mutate()` and obviuosly scala compiler converted it just to `def mutate() = this`. So F-bounded polimorphism proposed by you or the solution proposed in my answer is the only possible solution for Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a parameterized module for this situation:

```
trait GenotypeSystem {
  type Genotype <: GenotypeLike

  trait GenotypeLike {
    def makeRandom(): Genotype
    def mutate(): Genotype
  }
}

// Example implementation
object IntGenotypeSystem extends GenotypeSystem {
  case class Genotype(x: Int) extends GenotypeLike {
    def makeRandom() = copy(x = Random.nextInt(10))
    def mutate(): Genotype = copy(x = x + Random.nextInt(3) - 1)
  }
}

// Example abstract usage
def replicate(gs: GenotypeSystem)(g: gs.Genotype, n: Int): Seq[gs.Genotype] =
  Seq.fill(n)(g.mutate())
```

This approach lends itself easily to future modification and extension, such as adding other types to the `GenotypeSystem`.

Comment: `copy` with override arguments!! That's the ideal solution. I just [looked it up](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes). I had no idea. Thanks for that, and also for the many other fine points of this example that illustrate how things are done in Scala. You probably just saved me two weeks of stumbling around.

Answer (score 5):

You need [F-bounded polymorphism](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded):

```
abstract class Genotype[T <: Genotype[T]] {
  def makeRandom(): T  
  def mutate(): T      
}

class ConcreteGenotype extends Genotype[ConcreteGenotype] {
  def makeRandom(): ConcreteGenotype = ???
  def mutate(): ConcreteGenotype = ???
}
```

Comment: Oh well, I was afraid of that. Right now, for readability, I'm favoring maks's solution, since `A[B]` suggests (to me, at least) some additional semantic relationship of interest between `A` and `B`, whereas an abstract type doesn't really suggest anything and consequently seems better suited for "just there to help the compiler".

Answer (score 3):

```
abstract class Genotype {
  type T <: Genotype
  def makeRandom(): T  
  def mutate(): T      
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: This might work! Is there a way to avoid putting `type T = SpecificGenotype259` in the definition of every subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using covariant return types will work in your case?

```
abstract class Genotype {
  def makeRandom(): Genotype  // must return subclass type
  def mutate(): Genotype      // must return subclass type
}

class ConcreteGenotype(val a : Int) extends Genotype {
  override def makeRandom(): ConcreteGenotype = new ConcreteGenotype(a + 1)
  override def mutate(): ConcreteGenotype = new ConcreteGenotype(a + 2)
}

def useAbstractGenotype(g : Genotype) = g.mutate

val cg = new ConcreteGenotype(0) // cg: ConcreteGenotype = ConcreteGenotype@6c1c19c6
cg.mutate                        // res2: ConcreteGenotype = ConcreteGenotype@3fc1058a
useAbstractGenotype(cg)          // res3: Genotype = ConcreteGenotype@13515ded
```